# Don't redirect to Login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, security

I have this controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProfileSettings(ProfileSettingsInputModel model)
    {
       //some actions
       WebSecurity.Logout();
       return View(model);
    }
```

So I must get view page, but I can't see it, because I've logout. But I can see it and don't move tp Login Url(I specify it in the Web.config). But if I press F5(Refresh this page) I redirect to Login page. Who can I redirect to it correctly(without refresh)/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
 return View(model)
```

redirect to your login page.  If you are using the default mvc:

```
 return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
```